# How to run Broken DAGS in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, pipeline, directed-acyclic-graphs, modulenotfounderror

I am using Ubuntu to run Airflow DAGS on windows 10. I am able to only see the examples DAGS, and not the custom ones, because they are using Python eternal

```
Broken DAG: [/mnt/d/projects/pipeline/pipeline-v1/dags/prepare_data.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/mnt/d/projects/pipeline/pipeline-v1/dags/prepare_data.py", line 12, in <module>
    from astro.files import File
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'astro'

 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/mnt/d/projects/dg-fcpq-data-pipeline-v2/dg-fcpq-data-pipeline-v2/dags/prepare_data.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I have given the path of airflow.cfg file in the dags_folder variable to point to the project's path but I am not able to make the DAGS run.
How can I install the Python dependencies so that the DAGS could run? The project has a virtual environment where all the dependencies are installed, but I don't know how to link that to the Airflow webserver start.

Comment: can you do pip list and see whether you can see the libraries?

Comment: @Kulasangar yes I did, but I could only see the libraries installed in Ubuntu, not the ones installed on Windows, in the venv. I also tries to activate the venv and to start the pipeline in the venv environment, but there are still the DAGS import errors.

Comment: How exactly are you running Airflow in Windows? WSL?

Comment: @RNHTTR yes, I have installed Ubuntu for Windows and using WSL

Comment: This blog might be helpful: https://medium.com/international-school-of-ai-data-science/setting-up-apache-airflow-in-windows-using-wsl-dbb910c04ae0